# Преобразование в excel

Tags: excel

По ТЗ я должен запустить Excel файл и получить не читаемый набор символов, впоследствии преобразовать это в читаемый текст. Как выполнить преобразование?

Comment: Если что-то непонятно - уточняйте. Я уже сам свой бред не понимаю.

Comment: что значит "нечитаемый набор символов"? В какой "читаемый" текст нужно преобразовать?

Comment: @Bogdan если я правильно понимаю, то в каждом столбце будет не читаемый текст что-то на подобии сбитой кодировки

Comment: Всё это нужно будет преобразовать в новый excel файл, только уже читаемый, со слов куратора инвертировать

Comment: "Как выполнить преобразование?" Взять какой-либо язык программирования, например VBA. Открыть Excel и сделать преобразование, сохранить.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Открыть Excel и сделать преобразование, сохранить.

Comment: Так что мешает "Открыть Excel и сделать преобразование, сохранить"?

Comment: @nick_n_a я не работаю с excel как таковым на своей OC, а на площадке он будет, заранее файлов для прогона у меня и поэтому нужно знать как это делать на месте.

Comment: Уходя от ответа - вы не дали ответ на важный вопрос. Так найдите комп с виндой, поставьте себе excel и опробуйте то что хотите сделать, при чем тут "площадка"?  Мы не можем ответить на ваш вопрос, если вы сами не можете обьяснить что вам нужно. Сформулируйте, хотя бы, какой алгоритм вы подразумеваете под словом "преобразовать". Мы не медиумы, и кнопку "ок всё работает" делать не умеем:)

Comment: Куратор, кстати, должен обьяснить что вам делать, если у вас вопросы - вы должны его непрсредственно спрашивать. Ну а если вы в контрах с куратором - то что ж, увольняйтесь (если это работа), или сдавайте екзамен с комисией или договаривайтесь как-то.

Comment: Лично мне под слово "преобразование" - на ум сразу приходит в голову "фурье". На вопрос невозможно ответить верно, пока не будет ясно что за преобразование.

Comment: Насколько я понял, Excel здесь  где-то в дальнем незметном уголочке. Основное - шифрование/дешифрование данных. А тут раздолье - от простейших подмен символов до сложных алгоритмов. Ищите, показывайте, спрашивайте, что не получилось. Пока что вопроса нет, есть ТЗ